# AngularJs get date from object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, date, object

Can anyone help me please.I have this code :

```
 <h5>The price for parking is : </h5>{{ticket}}
```

Pay park

This is de list fron controller :

```
$scope.cars=[
{
    plate:'AA45UNW',
    color:'green',
    entrance:new Date()
}
];
```

The Button function :

```
$scope.calculateTicket=function(car){
        console.log("Inside calculateTicket");
        $scope.ticket=parkingFactory._calculateTicket;

    };
```

And this is the factory service :

```
app.factory("parkingFactory", function () {
    var _calculateTicket=function(car){
        var x=new Date();
        var departHour=x.getHours();
            $log.log("Depart Hour is :"+ departhour);
        var y=cars.entrance;
        var entranceHour=y.getHours();
            console.log("Entrance Hour is :"+ entranceHour);
        var parkingPeriod=departHour-entrancehour;
        var parkingPrice=parkingPeriod *10;

    return{
        period: parkingPeriod,

        price: parkingPrice

    };  

    };

    return {
        calculateTicket: _calculateTicket
    };


});
```

But when i try to retrieve the car.entrance it said that is undefined?
How to extract da Date()?
Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you have a typo in the `parkingFactory` change `var y=cars.entrance;` to `var y=car.entrance;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in above answer, You are accessing it wrong .

Your $scope.cars is an array , and you cannot access it like the way you are doing .

There are two ways to handle it :

**Solution 1**:
Defined it as object instead of array  :

```
$scope.cars={
plate:'AA45UNW',
color:'green',
entrance:new Date()
}
```

then access it like `$scope.cars.entrance`

**Solution 2** :

Access it differently by mentioning the index like :

```
$scope.cars[0].entrance;
```

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.cars` is array of object. You should specify index to access date from $scope.cars

Ex:

```
$scope.cars=[
{
    plate:'AA45UNW',
    color:'green',
    entrance:new Date()
}
];
```

You can acccess entrance using

```
$scope.cars[0].entrance;
```

Comment: It works the entrance. But still doesnt work the ticket.Nothing happened when i select a car and press Pay Park.